# UIActivityViewController share message cancel not showing

Tags: ios, swift3, ios11, uiactivityviewcontroller

When I want to share a URL with the message application via the `UIActivityViewController`. The cancel button is white (I guess because it still tappable)

It only appears on iOS 11, here the code use to present the UIActivityViewController and I already tried to change the color before presenting the `UIActivityViewController` but the button stay white :

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
   UIButton.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf:[UINavigationController.self]).tintColor = .blue
}
```

Here the code used to present the UIActivityViewController

```
let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [article.webReference], applicationActivities: [])
        self.present(vc, animated: false, completion:nil)

        vc.completionWithItemsHandler = {(s, ok, items, error) in
            switch s {
            case UIActivityType.mail?:
                print("mail")
                AnalyticsHelper.sharedInstance.sendShareMailEvent(articleUrl: article.webReference)
            case UIActivityType.postToFacebook?:
                print("facebook")
                AnalyticsHelper.sharedInstance.sendShareFacebookEvent(articleUrl: article.webReference)
            case UIActivityType.postToTwitter?:
                print("twitter")
                AnalyticsHelper.sharedInstance.sendShareTwitterEvent(articleUrl: article.webReference)
            default:
                print("others")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a same problem because of UIBarButtomItem.apperance().tintColor changed. Instead of changing default UI look I created my class of NavigationController which inherits from UINavigationController and in viewDidLoad method I have customise what I need. Next I changed all UInavigationController uses in storyboard and pure code to NavigationController. And now I can change controls for this class in AppDelegate, for example:

```
let navBarButton = UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [NavigationController.self])
navBarButton.tintColor = .white
```